# Working on the same store/state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flux, redux

What should I do to get Store with the same states in each Component in React-Native? Actually I use `createStore` in each Component, but this creates a new Store without previous state.

Comment: http://rackt.org/redux/docs/api/combineReducers.html

Comment: I wasn't clear enough. I want get the same instance of Store in each Component. Actually I am creating new instance by use createStore(combinedReducers);

Comment: Maybe create a container or parent component, and pass the state down to all child components with a single state instance passed down as props?

Comment: I am not sure is it a good solution. I want to know how other people fixed this problem. Probably I am using redux store in wrong way.

Comment: Well this problem is completely solved in React using react-redux. Here are the docs for using it with react native https://github.com/rackt/react-redux/tree/v3.1.0#react-native